# spark ui jobs tab not showing running

Tags: apache-spark, jobs

I've tried to find a solution to see my running jobs in spark UI.

I don't know why it is not showing running jobs.

==========================Figure=============================
[image]

==========================Figure=============================

Why is this happening?

Any Ideas?

Comment: is really any jobs running or ran in past ?

Comment: How  do you submit jobs?

Comment: Yes, I did. What the problem in jobs tab?